# Help with polynomials give zeros

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

My teacher hasn’t covered this type of material yet and I’m really struggling.
All I know is that it’s a third degree polynomial and the roots are $x=2$ and $x=-3i$. Also given is that the polynomial equals $60$ when $x=-1$.

What do I do whit this information and how can I construct the expanded polynomial with just this?

Comment: It would be easier if you knew the polynomial has rational coefficients. Is that given?

Comment: @coffeemath I guess you meant real roots too :)

Comment: @lonestudent True I should have said real coefficients in this comment. But certainly not necessarily real roots. [after all one given root here is not real.]

Answer (score 3):

I accept the coefficients of your polynomial are all real.

If the all coefficients are real, then you have

$$x_1=2, x_2=-3i, x_3=3i$$

Your polynomial is equivalent to

$$P(x)=A(x-2)(x-3i)(x+3i)=A(x-2)(x^2+9)$$

$$P(-1)=-30A=60\Longrightarrow A=-2$$

So, your polynomial equals to

$$P(x)=-2(x-2)(x^2+9)$$

Comment: All you need for this argument is that the polynomial has *real* coefficients.

Comment: @coffeemath you're Right! I mixed the words

Comment: Yes now it's right. Might be good to include fact that a poly with real coefficients has its non-real roots in conjugate pairs.

Comment: @coffeemath By the way, I realized that there will no irrational coefficient in the polynomial. Because, in our case $(a-bi)(a+bi)=a^2-b^2 \in\mathbb Q$. For this reason I slicked to word "rational".

Comment: lone student: But in problem statement only two roots $x=2,\ x=-3i$ were given. Your extra root $+3i$ was only implied if coefficients already known to be real. In fact OP may have been inaccurately saying "whose roots are..." when one should have said something like "among whose roots are". After all a third degree polynomial might have a double root.

Comment: @coffeemath I understand. If the coefficients are real, In this case we have always rational coefficients. ( mentally noticed this before I write) This is what I meant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120353/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-lone-student).

Comment: @lonestudent Very good answer$(+1)$. about your comment :"$(a-bi)(a+bi)=a^2-b^2 \in\mathbb Q$" I just want to mention that, it is $a^2+b^2$ although it doesn't influence on your conclusion.

Comment: @Soheil thank you. I noticed this later, but unfortunately the comment cannot be edited.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can make use of this fact:
\begin{gather*}
\text{For integers}\; a,b\ \text{and}\ c.\\
\text{if}\ ax^{2} +bx+c=0\ \text{has}\ x=di\ \text{as a root},\ \\
\text{then the other root of the equation must be}\ x=-di.
\end{gather*}
Utilizing this fact, with $d=-3$ from your question, the set of quadratic equations which have these roots are:
\begin{equation*}
c( x-3i)( x+3i) =c\left( x^{2} +9\right)
\end{equation*}
where $c$ is any rational number except $0$.
Similarly, the cubic equation that has roots $-2, 3i$ and $-3i$ is
\begin{equation*}
f( x) =c( x-2)( x-3i)( x+3i) =c( x-2)\left( x^{2} +9\right)
\end{equation*}
From your question $f(-1)= 60$, so
\begin{gather*}
c( -1-2)\left(( -1)^{2} +9\right) =60\\
c( -3)( 10) =60\\
c=\frac{60}{-30} =-2
\end{gather*}
Can you now complete the answer?